# Unable to group if there any null key occurs

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

```
Map<String, List<PartyInfo>> accountPartyInfoMap1 = partyInfoData.stream()
         .filter(a->Objects.nonNull(a.getPartyDisclosureTypeCode()))
         .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(PartyInfo::getPartyDisclosureTypeCode));
```

Is there a way I can filter null, I am still getting the error "element cannot be mapped to a null key"

Comment: If you have `filter`, there is no reason why you should end up with the `null` key during grouping still. Unless maybe there is a concurrent modification of the input to this stream.

Comment: Just to be sure: Objects is java.util.Objects, right?

Comment: The need to ask whether `Objects` is `java.util.Objects` shows that you’d be better off with `.filter(a -> a.getPartyDisclosureTypeCode() != null)`. It’s simpler, shorter, and immediately obvious to the reader.